# UITableView paging not accurately works swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagination

I have already implemented pagination in UITableView but somehow it's not working perfectly. If I scroll down  sometimes it gives me `Index out of bound error` even the lacking of scrolling back. 
Secondly, I cannot scroll up to top records.

- Page Number is important in service.
- I have sections in tableView.

```
var currentPage: Int = 0
var isLoadingList : Bool = false
```

Service:

```
func getListFromServer(_ pageNumber: Int){
    self.isLoadingList = false

        DataProvider.main.serviceGetData(SearchType: SearchType, PageNumber: pageNumber, callback: {success, result in

        do{
            if(success){
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let response = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: result! as! Data)
                self.Appdata = response.appointmentList

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
                return true
            }else{

                return false
            }
        }catch let error {

            print(error as Any)
            return false
        }
    })
    }
```

Paging & Scrolling code:

```
func loadMoreItemsForList(){
    currentPage += 1

        switch currentPage {
        case 1,2,3:
            getListFromServer(currentPage)
        default:
            print("no data")
        }
    }

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) > scrollView.contentSize.height ) && !isLoadingList){
            self.isLoadingList = true
            self.loadMoreItemsForList()
        }
    }
```

TableView Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return Appdata?[section].date ?? ""
    }
//
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return Appdata?.count ?? 0

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(80)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return Appdata?[section].appointmentList?.count ?? 0

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AppTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AppTableViewCell
        let dic = Appdata![indexPath.section].appointmentList![indexPath.row]

        cell.topLabel.text = dic.projectName
        cell.midLabel.text = dic.subTitle


        return cell 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are replacing your data source every time

```swift
self.Appdata = response.appointmentList
```

it should be

```swift
  self.Appdata?.append(contentsOf: response.appointmentListz ?? [])
```

Secondly when getting data set isLoadingList to be true to avoid making many request while scrolling and make it false again after getting response

```swift
func getListFromServer(_ pageNumber: Int){
        DataProvider.main.serviceGetData(SearchType: SearchType, PageNumber: pageNumber, callback: {success, result in
              self.isLoadingList = false
```

Finally do not forgot using [weak self] on your network closures

```swift
func getListFromServer(_ pageNumber: Int){
        DataProvider.main.serviceGetData(SearchType: SearchType, PageNumber: pageNumber, callback: { [weak self] success, result in
        guard let self = self else { return }
              self.isLoadingList = false
```

Comment: Thank you let me implement that and get back to you.